# Compilation error when defining and using std::map in C++

Tags: compiler-errors

This code:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>


typedef std::map<int,int> mymap;
mymap test;
test.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
```

Produces this compilation error:

```
In file included from fin.cc:35:0:

fin.h:14:1: error: 'test' does not name a type

test.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
```

What could cause this error?

Comment: you need to put `test.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));`  inside the `int main(){}` and it will compile with you without errors.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Put this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I put it thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `test.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));` inside the `int main(){}` and it will compile with you without errors.

Here is a full example with some test cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<int,int> mymap;
mymap test;

int main()
{
 map<int, int>::iterator itr; 
 
 test.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
 test.insert(std::make_pair(3,4));
 test.insert(std::make_pair(5,6));
 test.insert(std::make_pair(10,11));

 cout<<"Size: "<<test.size()<<endl;
 
    for (itr = test.begin(); itr != test.end(); ++itr) { 
        cout << "First: " << itr->first<< "  Second: " << itr->second <<endl; 
    } 
}
```

**Output:**
Size: 4
First: 1  Second: 2
First: 3  Second: 4
First: 5  Second: 6
First: 10  Second: 11